# Calculating Mode in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that will calculate the mode from a list.

```
letters = ['a','b','b','c','c']

from collections import Counter
def mode(myList):
    n = len(myList)  
    data = Counter(myList) 
    get_mode = dict(data) 
    mode = [k for k, v in get_mode.items() if v == max(list(data.values()))] 
    if len(mode) == n: 
        get_mode = "No mode found"
    else: 
        get_mode = ' , '.join(map(str, mode)) 
    return(get_mode)

print (mode(letters))
```

**Main Problem** - In the case of this list (letters) the function returns " b , c " when it should in fact print "No Mode". 
*Can anyone please explain why this happens and how I can fix it?*

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: What constitues an "external library"? The standard library has a `Counter` in its collections module, which could work fine for this case.

Comment: Wouldn't even need `Counter`. It's trivial to implement with regular dictionaries using `get`. The OP really needs to show what they tried so we can try help with that approach

Comment: You should include the code in the linked images *into* your question, format it properly, and provide input (and expected output) that triggers your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *much* easier way to do what you want: Counters have a function `.most_common(n)` which takes `n`, how many results you want.

```
def get_mode(lst):
    counter = Counter(lst)
    if len(counter) > 1:  # ensure at least 2 unique elements
        possible_mode, next_highest = counter.most_common(2)
        if possible_mode[1] > next_highest[1]:
            return possible_mode[0]
    return "No mode"
```

This gives us:

```
>>> get_mode(['a', 'b'])  # Same highest count
'No mode'
>>> get_mode(['a', 'b', 'b'])  # Has a mode
'b'
>>> get_mode(['b', 'b'])  # Not enough unique elements to calculate a mode
'No mode'
```